# Authentication for mongo db

Tags: mongodb, authentication

How to Add Authentication for mongodb at the time of typing start-up command:

```
root@NSBLR:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1

connecting to: test
```

Also, Server has startup warnings:

```
2015-04-02T09:43:04.775+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-04-02T09:43:04.775+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-04-02T09:43:04.775+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-04-02T09:43:04.775+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-04-02T09:43:04.775+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-04-02T09:43:04.775+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-04-02T09:43:04.775+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that this is a community for software developers. Your question, however, is not about developing software based on MongoDB but about configuring MongoDB. This requires the expertise of a database administrator. So I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com. In addition, you are actually asking not one but two rather unrelated questions. 1. enabling authentication and 2. why and how to configure transparent_hugepage. I would recommend you to ask these as separate questions.

Comment: Those startup warnings aer merely to display the best settings that should really be switched on for your particular configuration of MongoDB. They are not required but are good for performance normally.

Comment: Also please read the documentation on authentication, it has a tutorial and definitions of how to do all this